# Reorder legend in ggplot object

Tags: r, legend, ggplot2

I met some trouble when dealing with the order of ggplot legend. 
I plotted three lines in one graph, and I tried to use 'scale_colour_mannual' to change the order as the line from top to bottom, but it does not work.
The code I use:

```
ggplot() + #geom_point(data = Gcross_tumor, aes(x = 
Gcross_tumor$r*1000, y = Gcross_tumor$theo)) +
geom_line(data = Gcross_tumor, aes( x= Gcross_tumor$r*1000, y = 
Gcross_tumor$km, colour = 'Tumor'), size = 1.5) + 
geom_line(data = Gcross_normal, aes( x= Gcross_normal$r*1000, y = 
Gcross_normal$km, colour = 'Normal tissue'), size = 1.5) +
geom_line(data = Gcross_invasive, aes( x= Gcross_invasive$r*1000, y = 
Gcross_invasive$km,colour = 'Invasive margin'), size = 1.5) + 
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 18)) +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
xlab('Section') +
scale_colour_manual(name = '',values=c('Tumor' = "#F97A76",'Invasive 
margin' = "#65FFA1", 'Normal tissue' = "#0581DD"))
```

But the plot is like:
[image]
I want the order of legend correlates with the order of lines from top to bottom, any suggestion?

Comment: There's no GIS angle here so you should try posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a more appropriate question for stackoverflow.com, but I'll go ahead and answer.  First off, you should probably combine all your different dataframes into one, with a separate column for the feature of interest:

```
library(dplyr)

Gcross_normal$feature <- "normal"
Gcross_tumor$feature <- "tumor"
Gcross_invasive$feature <- "invasive"

Gcross <- Reduce(bind_rows, list(Gcross_normal, Gcross_tumor, Gcross_invasive))
```

Then, you can make a ggplot with only one call to `geom_line`, with the feature as an aesthetic:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=Gcross, aes(x=r*1000, y=km, color=feature)) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 18)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
  xlab('Section') +
  scale_colour_manual(name = '', values=c('Tumor' = "#F97A76", 'Invasive = "#65FFA1", 'Normal tissue' = "#0581DD"))
```

Now that all of the features are in one dataframe, you can change the levels of the factor with `relevel`, which change the order of the legend items in ggplot.  So

```
Gcross$feature <- relevel(Gcross$feature, "Tumor")
```

will make "Tumor" the first level in the factor, and will make it the first item on a ggplot legend.